# Android testing RxJava 2

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

Having an error when testing RxJava code. It fils when I call `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` in ViewModel. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    ...
    at com.cardsimulator.ui.MainViewModel.executeCommand(MainViewModel.java:56)
    at com.cardsimulator.ui.MainViewModelTest.testExecuteCommand_NormalCommand(MainViewModelTest.java:54)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `AndroidSchedulers.mainThead()` for testing purpose. You can use `Schedulers.trampoline()` instead. It basically executes all the tasks on the current thread without any queueing and the timed overloads use blocking sleep as well.

You can use injection framework (as Dagger 2) for injecting the right scheduler. Or simply you can add this in your test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupTest() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(
            __ -> Schedulers.trampoline());
}
```